# Parsing CSVs for only one value

Tags: python, csv, parsing, ssis

I am trying to parse data from CSV files. The files are in a folder and I want to extract data and write them to the db. However the csvs are not set up in a table format. I know how to import csvs into the db with the for each loop container, adding data flow tasks, and importing with OLE DB Destination.

The problem is just getting one value out of these csvs. The format of the file is as followed:

```
Title        Title 2            
Date saved  ##/##/####  ##:## AM        
Comment             
[ Main ]                
No. Measure  Output Unit of measure 


1  Name  8  µm  
    Count   0   pcs     
[ XY Measure ]              
    X           
    Y           
    D           
[ Area ]                
No. Area    Unit    Perimeter   Unit
```

All I want is just the output which is "8", to snatch the name of the file to make it name of the result or add it to a column, and the date and time to add to their own columns.
I am not sure which direction to head into and i hope someone has some things for me to look into. Originally, I wasn't sure if I should do the parsing externally (python) before using SQL server. If anyone knows another way I should use to get this done please let me know. Sorry for the unclear post earlier.

The expect outcome:

```
Filename    Date         Time      Outcome 


jnnnnnnn    ##/##/####     ##:##        8
```

Comment: I think python will work, but can you post the specific requirements and how the files look and what are the filenames (what do you mean filename as identifier?) If the value is in the same place then it will be easy. Post what you have right now and what is the expected output.

Comment: @Wajahat ok I fully edited the post. Sorry, about that.

Comment: I don't think this is in csv format. Have you copy pasted it from excel or some text editor?

Comment: @Wajahat I said the same thing about the format. I copied it and pasted from the editor too look exactly the same as it is displayed.

Comment: Which editor have you been using? Can you post some screen shots for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
filename = # from the from the path of the file you're parsing

# define appropriate vars

for row in csv_file:
    if row.find('Date saved') > 0:
        row = row.replace('Date saved ')            
        date_saved = row[0:row.find(' ')]

        row = row.replace(date_saved + ' ')
        time = row[0:row.find(' ')]
    elif row.find(u"\u03BC"):
        split_row = row.split(' ')
        outcome = split_row[2]

    # add filename,date_saved,time,outcome to data that will go in DB
```

Comment: To be clear, I was assuming that each file consists of the 15 lines above, but this should work even if you had a file that was repeating the lines over and over again. Also assuming that you'd be dropping this within your `for file in files` loop.